# Get array object with specific properties axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am getting a JSON from an API call via axios and currently displaying the JSON using vue.

Here's my JSON Object from the console:

```
0:
  category_id: "categ1"
  item_name: "item1"
  price: 100
  stock: 155
1:
  category_id: "categ2"
  item_name: "item2"
  price: 100
  stock: 155
2:
  category_id: "categ1"
  item_name: "item3"
  price: 100
  stock: 155
3:
  category_id: "categ3"
  item_name: "item4"
  price: 100
  stock: 155
```

Here's my vue mounted function (i am using axios):

```
mounted () {    
  axios.get('link_for_api_endpoint', {  
    headers : { 
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token,
    },
    params: {
      limit: 250
    }
  })
    .then((response) => {
      this.data = response.data.items;
      //console.log(response);  
      $("#ldr").hide(); 
      removeLoader();   
    })  
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);   
    })  
    .then(function () { 

    }); 
}
```

What I want to do is I want to only get the data that has a category value "categ1" instead of the whole json object. How do i achieve this?

Comment: jquery? for what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in case the response is an array of objects.

```js
const result = response.filter(item => item.category_id === 'categ1');
```

In the result array you will have objects with categ1 as categoryId

Comment: you dont need to parse it axios doing it for you

Comment: Thanks for the catch, updated answer to use ````filter```` instead of ````find```` and removed ````JSON.parse````